# why navigationbar on emulator iphone does not appear?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i am learning to programing IOS swift xcode 10. i added a navigation controller and i have a viewcontroller and i added a navigation item but when i start the app it does not appear , i have a scrollview too. thanks.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

The error in constraint is about the content size of the scrollview but i dont think so that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation Item is just the holder for the buttons in the navigation bar of child View Controller.

Try inserting Bar Button Item to your Navigation Item in the child View Controller.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you are saying

Comment: I'm sorry, from the pictures above I assumed that the Navigation Item in Interface builder is empty, but I can see that you have a button in there. Is it Bar Button Item?

Comment: Also how are you instantiating the viewController? As the navigation Item is missing, is it possible that you are going directly to the child view controller - bypassing the navigation controller, that is responsible for the toolbar

Comment: Can you post the code you use to show the view controller?